# Proper XML design for nested entities

Tags: xml, tags, nested

I am a newbie in XML and I have to design an xml where each node may have child nodes and 
each child node may have child node again, which xml design i have to follow and what names i will keep for child nodes ? Please help .

Thanks in advance,
Dileep

Comment: Without any information about the sort of data you are trying to describe in XML, it will be impossible for anyone to provide you with an answer.

Comment: hi , yes, i can show you the structure , please help                       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
 <message name="ABC001">
  <attributes>
   <attribute name="A" class="A001">
    <attribute name="childA" class="C001" />
    <!-- again i have to add attributes tag as child to childA - nested -->
   </attribute>
  </attributes>
 </message>
 <message name="ABC002">
  <attributes>
   <attribute name="A" class="A002">
    <attribute name="childA" class="C002" />
   </attribute>
  </attributes>
 </message>
</config>

Comment: Well, there's nothing really wrong with the format you have here.  I'm  not sure what the question is.

Comment: Hi DWRoelands, Thanks for your time, let me clarify, i can give the above format , but how can i parse this xml since i have duplicate tag names inside parent?

Comment: How you parse the XML is going to depend on what platform you're using.  Python?  Perl?  VB.NET?  PHP?  You're going to want to resarch "XPATH", which is a way to query XML documents.

Comment: hanks DWRoelands, am using java, so Xpath would be better option ? Is there any other options also ? –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks to be a decent tutorial on parsing XML in Java using XPATH.

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-xml-xpath-tutorial-parse-xml/

Comment: Thanks a lot DWRoelands for spending your valuable time. Let me try to explore xpath ..